# Using fastify server in nest js for file uploading

Tags: nestjs, fastify-multipart

Property 'multipart' does not exist on type 'FastifyRequest<RouteGenericInterface, RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, FastifySchema, FastifyTypeProviderDefault, unknown, FastifyBaseLogger, ResolveFastifyRequestType<...>>'.

22     const mp = await req.multipart(this.handler, onEnd);
~~~~~~~~~

[This is the image of my code i have tried but it gives the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExhBd.png)

Comment: Why would `isMultipart()` exist on `FastifyRequest`? Are you using some sort of package for this? There is [`@nest-lab/fastify-multer`](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nest-lab/tree/main/packages/fastify-multer) which has an integration like Nest's existing multer integration, but with fastify specific support